# SharePoint Continuous Crawl after index reset

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search, crawl, index-reset

Using SharePoint 2013, we had to reset index, then we enabled **Continuous Crawl** I am not sure about the inner workings of this type of crawl. as I am looking at the crawl logs, it seems that Full crawl has not complete yet and at 7:00 PM everyday it launches a continuous crawl as shown below:

[image]

My questions:
1. Do I need to wait for Full crawl to complete? Or Shall I disabled it a do a full crawl and once it is done, I can enable continuous crawl?
2. Why Continuous crawl starts everyday at 7 PM? Where can I find this setting?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the below about the continuous crawl, all clarifications will be cleared.

- We cannot run **multiple full crawls** or **multiple incremental
  crawls** for the same content source at the same time. However,
  **multiple continuous** crawls can run at the same time.
- Therefore, even if one continuous crawl is processing a large content update, another continuous crawl can start at the predefined time interval and crawl other updates.
- Continuous crawls of a particular content repository can also occur
  while a full or incremental crawl is in progress for the same repository.

**How To disable continuous crawls for a content source**

Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is an administrator for the Search service application.

In Central Administration, in the Application Management section, click Manage service applications.

Click the Search service application.

On theSearch_Service_Application_Name: Search Administration page, in the Quick Launch, under Crawling, click Content Sources.

On theSearch_Service_Application_Name: Manage Content Sources page, click the SharePoint content source for which you want to disable continuous crawls.

In the Crawl Schedules section, clear Enable Incremental Crawls. This disables continuous crawls.

To confirm that you want to disable continuous crawls, click OK.

Optional: click Edit schedule to change the schedule for incremental crawls, and then click OK.

On theSearch_Service_Application_Name: Edit Content Source page, click OK.

Verification: On theSearch_Service_Application_Name: Manage Content Sources page, verify that the Status column has changed to Idle. This might take some time, because all URLs that remain in the crawl queue are still crawled after you disable continuous crawls.

For more details please read the below MSDN article :

[Manage continuous crawls in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/manage-continuous-crawls)

Answer (score 0):

1.If you have done reset index, you need to wait for Full crawl to complete.
You can disabled it a do a full crawl and once it is done, you can enable continuous crawl.

2.By default, The "Continuous Crawl" will launch the crawl at regular intervals.

You can find the settings by navigate to CA->application management->manage service applications->search service application->content sources->edit a content source->edit schedule:

[image]